# MATLAB: vectorized assignment from double array to cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, vectorization

I have three arrays, all the same size:

```
xout        % cell array
xin         % numeric array of doubles
b           % logical array
```

How can I take the elements of xin that correspond to the indices where b is true, and assign them to the corresponding places in xout?

```
>> xout = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux'};
>> xin = [1, 2, 3, 4];
>> b = (xin ~= 2);       % yields [1 0 1 1] in this case
>> xout{b}=xin(b);
??? The right hand side of this assignment has too few values 
to satisfy the left hand side.

>> xout(b)=xin(b);
??? Conversion to cell from double is not possible.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the function [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert the right hand side to a cell array before assigning it to `xout`:

```
xout(b) = num2cell(xin(b));
```